# Post json file to my REST service in java

Tags: java, json, angularjs, rest, jpa

I'm trying  to post data from my Angular js form to be saved to the database using REST service using Java.
below is my code for the rest

```
@Stateless
@Path("driverprops")

public class DriverPropFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<DriverProp> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.mycompany_groupProjectBackend_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU")
    private EntityManager em;

public DriverPropFacadeREST() {
    super(DriverProp.class);
}

@POST
@Override
@Consumes({ "application/json"})
public void create(DriverProp entity) {
    super.create(entity);
}
```

**hers is part of my driverprop class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;



 @Entity
    @Table(name = "DriverProp")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM   `DriverProp d"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByDriverID", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.driverID = :driverID"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByGear", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.gear = :gear"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByChangeUpRPM", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.changeUpRPM = :changeUpRPM"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByChangeDownRPM", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.changeDownRPM = :changeDownRPM"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByPreferredMaxRPM", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.preferredMaxRPM = :preferredMaxRPM"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByPreferredMinRPM", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.preferredMinRPM = :preferredMinRPM"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByDecisionTime", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.decisionTime = :decisionTime"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByMaxAccn", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.maxAccn = :maxAccn"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByMaxBreaking", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.maxBreaking = :maxBreaking"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByMaxStraightSpeed", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.maxStraightSpeed = :maxStraightSpeed"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "DriverProp.findByMaxCornerSpeed", query = "SELECT d FROM DriverProp d WHERE d.maxCornerSpeed = :maxCornerSpeed")})
    public class DriverProp implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Column(name = "DriverID")
        private Integer driverID;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "Gear")
        private int gear;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ChangeUpRPM")
        private float changeUpRPM;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "ChangeDownRPM")
        private float changeDownRPM;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "PreferredMaxRPM")
        private float preferredMaxRPM;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "PreferredMinRPM")
        private float preferredMinRPM;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "DecisionTime")
```

**My Question**
now i need an angular js that will send JSON file and that JSON should be saved to database using the REST services.. any idea to achieve that using angular fr client..

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- classic ajax requests (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)
- angular $http ([Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post.))
- angular $resource ([Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource.) with [implementation example](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html))
- angular modules like restangular ([Restangular readme](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#restangular))

For a while I used restangular, it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Witrh Angular, the easiest way is to use `$resource`. In your case, it would something like that:

```
var app = (...)

app.factory('DriverPropFacadeREST', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://(...)/driverprops/:id', {id:'@id'});
});

app.controller('DriverPropController', function($scope, DriverPropFacadeREST) {
    var inputData = { 'driverID': 'value', (...) };
    DriverPropFacadeREST.save(inputData, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        (...)
    });
});
```

See this link in the Angular reference documentation for more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource.

You could also use the low level API `$http`, as described below:

```
app.controller('DriverPropController', function($scope, $http) {
    var inputData = { 'driverID': 'value', (...) };
    $http.post('http://(...)/driverprops', inputData)
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // this callback will be called asynchronously
              // when the response is available
         })
         .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
              // called asynchronously if an error occurs
              // or server returns response with an error status.
         });
});
```

See this link in the Angular reference documentation for more details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry